# Многопоточность в работе парсера grab на python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, парсер, grab

Возможно ли ускорить работу простого парсера гугла, заставить работать в несколько потоков, и желательно чтоб не банил гугл мой IP

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from grab import Grab
import time

def google(name):
    g = Grab()
    g.proxylist.load_file('proxy1.txt')
    host = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s' % name.replace(' ', '+')
    try:
        g.go(host)
        return g.doc.select('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text().replace(',',' ')
    except:
        return None

f = open('key.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    print (line.strip(), '-', google(line))
    time.sleep (1)
```

Comment: threads = [5]
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=google(name))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

Comment: напишите свое решение в ответ

Comment: Какое именно решение? решения как бы нету)

Comment: А "threads = [5] for..." ?

Comment: это предположение, не работает и оно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

urls = [
    'http://www.python.org',
    'http://www.python.org/about/',
    'http://www.python.org/doc/',
    'http://www.python.org/download/',
]

def go(count=1):
    t = time.clock()
    pool = ThreadPool(count)
    results = pool.map(urlopen, urls)
    print('Pool: {:.3f} seconds, results: {}'.format(time.clock() - t, results))


t = time.clock()
results = []
for url in urls:
    result = urlopen(url)
    results.append(result)
print('Single thread: {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))

go(3)
```

Консоль:

```
Single thread: 43.660 seconds
Pool: 24.024 seconds, results: [<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02B3BBB0>, <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02B3BB70>, <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02B3BB10>, <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02BD5370>]
```

**UPDATE**

```
def google(name):
    g = Grab()
    g.proxylist.load_file('proxy1.txt')
    host = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s' % name.replace(' ', '+')
    try:
        g.go(host)
        return g.doc.select('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text().replace(',',' ')
    except:
        return

with open('key.txt') as f:
    pool = ThreadPool(2)
    results = pool.map(google, f.readlines())
```

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, но я не совсем понимаю, как теперь сюда вставить то, что мне нужно парсить (блок id=''resultStats'' из страницы выдачи google), чтоб выдавались результаты в виде "ключ - содержимое блока resultStats". и ключи загружались из файла

Comment: В `pool.map(urlopen, urls)` вместо `urlopen` вставляете свою функцию, принимающую хотя бы один параметр, а вместо `urls` -- список параметров

Comment: т.е. grab мне уже не использовать, простите, если задаю тупые вопросы, но запутался совсем уже

Comment: Скажите, что в вашем коде вы бы захотели распараллелить? Что должно выполняться в несколько потоков?

Comment: ну вот есть файл с ключами, эти ключи вставляются в строку поиска гугла 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s' % name.replace(' ', '+') 
далее вытягивается блок из открытой данной страницы с id="resultStats" и выдается в виде "ключ" - "содержимое блока 'resultStats'. и при этом использоватся прокси должны.

так вот многопоточность хотелось использовать в паралельном открытии строк из файла и выдаче результатов не по одному, а по три-четыре хотя бы в сек.

Comment: Обновил ответ для вашего примера, попробуйте